# From rows to a single column

Tags: r, reshape

There are many files for which data is in the following form

```
year Jan Feb Mar ...........Dec
1990 x1  x2   x3           x12    
1991 y1  y2   y3           y12
```

.
.

```
2000 z1 z2 z3             z12
```

I want to transpose each of the rows and stack them as a column to get the time series as

```
x1
x2


..
x12
y1
y2
..
y12
z1
.
.
z12
```

I have looked at the reshape package but not clear as to how it will apply in this problem.
Any ideas for doing this in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `melt()` from the "reshape2" package is what you are looking for:

```
library(reshape2)
DF <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Year Jan Feb Mar 
1990 x1  x2   x3     
1991 y1  y2   y3 ")

DF2 <- melt(DF, id.vars="Year")
DF2[order(DF2$Year), ]
#   Year variable value
# 1 1990      Jan    x1
# 3 1990      Feb    x2
# 5 1990      Mar    x3
# 2 1991      Jan    y1
# 4 1991      Feb    y2
# 6 1991      Mar    y3
```

Comment: Well, I want all the monthly values in order. 1990 Jan Feb Mar ...Dec Then 1991 Jan Feb Mar ... Dec as in the question. Its a time series data and the order requires stacking the transposes of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data is called `dat`, I would like to suggest:

```
as.vector(t(dat[,-1]))
```